# What emotion/sensory feeling is this?

Tags: social-psychology, emotion, behavior

The facial expression is: 2C+6+12+24A (Facial Action Coding System)

I can't find out what expression and emotion this represents. Also if anybody knows a site which lists more than the universal expressions and their Facial Action Coding representation, that would be helpful.

This is the closest expression I can find; note but it doesn't express 2C: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo5Th.jpg